# do block in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I am trying to write a function in Haskell that takes two lists and returns an element common to both.
I am using the following approach but it gives a parse error and says to put `<-` statements in a do block. How can I implement the condition in the do block?

What I'm trying:

```
present (xs)(ys) = concat[ x | x <- xs && x <-ys ]
```

Comment: You may want to take a look at some more basic Haskell tutorials. For this example, maybe try looking at the "I'm a list comprehension" section of Starting Out in LYAH: http://learnyouahaskell.com/starting-out

Comment: Just to be clear on what you are looking for.  You are trying to get a list of all the elements that exist in both input lists?

Comment: Well yeah in this case it will give me a list but I actually need only one.

Comment: I know I can do the task recursively, but I was just trying to do it this way.

Comment: You are trying to write a list comprehension, not a do block. The error message mentions do blocks because the syntax you are using for the list comprehension is wrong. I second jkeuhlen's suggestion of having a look at that section of LYAH.

Comment: Prolog style variable unification does not exist. If you have two different bindings for value `x` they are simply different variables with one shadowing the other. It does not mean "The first and second values are equal".  For equality you should use `a == b`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<-` doesn't say "`x` is in `xs`"; it says "take `x` from `xs`". It's not a boolean expression you can combine with others using `&&`, but part of the syntax of a list comprehension. If you want to use a list comprehension, it would be

```
present xs ys = [x | x <- xs, x `elem` ys]
```

where you take each element from `xs`, but only use it if it is also an element of `ys`. You don't need `concat`.

Note this takes *all* elements common to `xs` and `ys` (i.e., it's the set intersection). If you are only interested in a single arbitrary item (most easily, the first), then you don't need a list comprehension at all:

```
present [] _ = Nothing
present (x:xs) ys | x `elem` ys = Just x
                  | otherwise = present xs ys
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know about  `elem`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you're doing this for coursework and you're not allowed to use the standard library.

But in the real world, you typically want some kind of "set" object, such as the Haskell standard library's Data.Set.Set.

```
import qualified Data.Set as S

commonElems :: (Ord a) => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
commonElems firstList = filter (\ elem -> S.member elem set)
  where 
    set = S.fromList firstList

main :: IO ()
main = print $ commonElems [1, 2, 3, 55] [55, 3, 4, 5]
--[55,3]
```

(Also if you just want the first common element then the function `head` works.)